# Is dalvik agent header unique for any device in http connections?

Tags: android, user-agent, dalvik

Agents with dalvik request to server contain some characters after `Build`. for example:

```
Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; C6902 Build/14.4.A.0.157)

Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.0.0; SM-G930F Build/R16NW)
```

**Question**: Is it unique for any android device/emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those characters represent the build "number" which is the current build version running on the device.  If I understand correctly your question then no, it cannot be use to identify a unique device.

You can check the Android source website and verify the current build version for devices (like the Pixel phones) running Android 8.1.  Those alphanumeric characters are used to identify the Android version built for a specific device, but you can't identify a **unique** device based on it.

https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if you can add a reference, then I mark your post as answer to the question.

Comment: So, if it's the build number, why it is different with the same build installed on android 4 and android  7?

Comment: The build number on the user-agent is the one for the custom Android used by the vendor for that device.  Every vendor has a different way to define this build version string, it can be only numbers or alpha numeric characters.  Even if two phones has the same Android version, the build number can be completely different.